# sync AES ecnryption between cryptoJS and openSSL (ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption, openssl, aes, cryptojs

I can't get same result when encrypting using CryptoJS or Ruby's OpenSSL

JS code

```
k=CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('ca978112ca1bbdcafac231b39a23dc4da786eff8147c4e72b9807785afee48bb');
iv=CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('3e23e8160039594a33894f6564e1b1348bbd7a0088d42c4acb73eeaed59c009d');
r=CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("hello", k, { iv: iv });
alert(r.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64));
```

and in Rails

```
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES.new(256, :CBC)
cipher.encrypt
cipher.key = 'ca978112ca1bbdcafac231b39a23dc4da786eff8147c4e72b9807785afee48bb'
cipher.iv = '3e23e8160039594a33894f6564e1b1348bbd7a0088d42c4acb73eeaed59c009d'
enc = cipher.update('hello')+cipher.final
puts Base64.encode64(enc)
```

the 2 results do not give the same encrypted message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IV has to be 16 bytes or 128-bit long, because AES has a blocksize of 128-bit. Your current IV has 32 bytes. So there is probably a difference between how CryptoJS and OpenSSL treat an IV that is too long.

Comment: thanks ! that helped
Also for future references,  key and iv passed to cipher in ruby must be converted to binary and cannot be assigned as plain hex.

Comment: @WKx wow. I would never have figured that out. So glad you left this comment. I was this close to ending it all.